# How to show a snakbar with Lottie animation in start from a recycler view adapter

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar, autolink

I am making a chat app and I want to add a feature like telegram to copy links ,phone numbers and etc.. from long clicking on an auto link.I used [this](https://github.com/saket/Better-Link-Movement-Method) library to add long click listeners on a auto link.I implemented it successfully.But when I do this, i want to show a Lottie animation in the start like [this](https://vimeo.com/645505115) but on long click of a link.
I tried many answer but I get an exception.I already made the layout for custom snakbar.It is given below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="56dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/_3sdp"
android:backgroundTint="@color/snakbar_background"
app:cardCornerRadius="@dimen/_4sdp">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <com.airbnb.lottie.LottieAnimationView
        android:id="@+id/lottieSnakbar"
        android:layout_width="35dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/_10sdp"
        app:lottie_rawRes="@drawable/copy"
        app:lottie_autoPlay="true"
        app:lottie_loop="false"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Text copied to clipboard"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:theme="?snackbarTextViewStyle"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

</LinearLayout>

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

Now how can I achieve this?

Comment: Perhaps you add other codes for us to try what you have currently, but i suppose [medium](https://medium.com/@fabionegri/make-snackbar-great-again-51edf7c940d4) would help out with the animation you want to achieve

Comment: it indeed is helpful, but it is for Kotlin, but I want for java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an interface in the adapter. And receive and show snakbar from activity

Answer (score 0):

You could use `localBroadcast` and broadcast a local  signal from the adapter and let the other `Activity`(probably receiver) handle snakbar.

```
AdapterClass{
   LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = null;
   
   void sendB(parms){
      if(localBroadcastManager != null){
            localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(Intent("NOTIFICATION_RECEIVER"))
      }

   onCreateViewHolder(){
       localBroadcastManager = LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext)
      }

  onBindViewHolder(){
      if(someCondition){
           sendB(parms);
    }
}
```

then receive it from an activity then call snakBar

Comment: are you talking about a interface?

Comment: yes, just sent the local broadcast from the adapter(i did the same).

Comment: or just pass the snakbar object to adpater